# Active EN Pin When Device is Plugged in

Tags: usb, boost

I'm looking to use a TPS61xxx series DC-DC boost converter for a charger, but I only want the converter to be active once the USB cable is plugged into the receptacle.

Now from my understanding, some devices look at the resistance on the end of the D+/D- lines and decide how much current the device is allowed to pull from the charger. So is using the data lines to activate the EN pin a bad idea? I'm assuming the IC has its own internal resistance, and that might confuse the device being charged. If that's the case, then what's the best way to send a signal to the EN pin to activate the converter when the USB is plugged in without using a switch?

Comment: I'd use some sort of op-amp/comparator that measures the current by monitoring the voltage across a shunt resistor in series with the USB power line. An op-amp would amplify this voltage to one that the comparator can use, and the comparator would compare the op-amp output with the Vref to see if current is being drawn from the USB

Comment: In the design I currently have, the data lines are shorted to one another so the device can establish how much it's able to pull from the charger. So there wouldn't be any shunt resistors available. Could I still use the comparator on the raw D+/D- pins?

Comment: Will the device ever be plugged into a computer?

Comment: Nope. It doesn't have an MCU or anything that would require it to be plugged into a computer. Just a battery and the converter.

Comment: The shunt resistor would need to be put in series with the +5V power line, not the data line.